# how to delete the selected row on click of checkbox with condition check

Tags: jquery

I am trying to delete the row checking the the condition where if selected with input field value is 0 (there is one input field), then only row should be deleted.
please let me know where is the problem. it is deleted both the selected row even if once input filed is 0.

```
var purchased = $(".purchased input");
/*remove selected item start*/
$('.removeselected').on('click', function(){        
    var checkedstatus = $(".checker input:checked");

    $('.checker').each(function() {
        if((checkedstatus) && (purchased.val() == 0)){
            console.log("Varified");
            checkedstatus.parents(".renderedItem").remove();
        }else{
            console.log("not varified");
        }
    });
});
/*remove selected item end*/
```

Comment: Show your HTML. How `purchased  input` is related to `checker input:checked`

Comment: Without HTML we cannot know relations between DOM elements.

Comment: actually there is a row....on the left side there is checkbox and the right side there is inputbox....if i checked checkbox than it should check weather  the inputbox value is 0 or not...if yes than only it should delete the row

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each checked checkbox, then check purchased input value within the same row and remove the element if it's 0

```
$('.removeselected').on('click', function(){     
    $('.checker .checkboxitem:checked').each(function () {
        if ($(this).closest('.row').find('.purchased input').val() == 0) {
            $(this).closest('.checker').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
$('.removeselected').on('click', function(){     
$('.checker .checkboxitem:checked').each(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('.row').find('.purchased input').val() == 0) {
        $(this).closest('.checker').remove();
    }
});
```

});