# Getting Conflict on adding the class

Tags: jquery, html

There is two div, on click of one private div, public div it adds clickable class there. but the same toggle div coming in multiple rows and it is creating conflict of the class.

[DEMO](http://%20jsfiddle.net/1bzats85/6)

Comment: Here is the linkL: https://jsfiddle.net/1bzats85/6/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1bzats85/7/

Answer (score 2):

You need to select element based on the clicked object. Here what you can do is select based on it's parent element, you can get parent element using **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)**

```js
/*Private Public Start*/
$(".public").click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(this).addClass("clickable");
  $(".bluetext", parent).addClass("hidden")
    .removeClass("show");
  $(".private", parent).removeClass("clickable");
});
$(".private").click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(this).addClass("clickable");
  $(".bluetext", parent).addClass("show")
    .removeClass("hidden");
  $(".public", parent).removeClass("clickable");
});
/*Private Public End*/
```

```css
.categorypanel .publicprivate {
  border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  width: 118px;
  height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 13px;
}
.categorypanel .publicprivate .public {
  width: 57px;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.categorypanel .publicprivate .private {
  width: 57px;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.categorypanel .publicprivate .clickable {
  background: #7961aa;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 13px;
  cursor: context-menu;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categorypanel">
  <div class="publicprivate">
    <div class="public pull-left clickable">public</div>
    <div class="private pull-left">private</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="publicprivate">
    <div class="public pull-left clickable">public</div>
    <div class="private pull-left">private</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="publicprivate">
    <div class="public pull-left clickable">public</div>
    <div class="private pull-left">private</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RohitSalviya : glad to help :)

Comment: can you please hlep me solve this issue please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014569/how-to-delete-the-selected-row-on-click-of-checkbox-with-condition-check/33017028?noredirect=1#comment53857951_33017028

Comment: actually it is generating dynamically while loading the checkbox. below is the generated code. <div class="checker"><span class="checked"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxitem"></span></div>

Comment: where is `purchased` input field for `purchased==0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91810/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-rohit-salviya).